# How can I use a placeholder in my Formbuilder (Symfony 4)?

Tags: symfony, oop, placeholder, formbuilder

I want to use a placeholder for my Password field (in the case it is not empty):

```
$formBuilder->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'), 'label' => 'Password','placeholder' => '...',));
```

But I get an error message:

> The option "placeholder" does not exist. Defined options are:
>   "action", "allow_extra_fields", "always_empty", "attr",
>   "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "compound",
>   "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection",
>   "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class",
>   "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping",
>   "extra_fields_message", "help", "inherit_data", "invalid_message",
>   "invalid_message_parameters", "label", "label_attr", "label_format",
>   "mapped", "method", "post_max_size_message", "property_path",
>   "required", "translation_domain", "trim", "upload_max_size_message",
>   "validation_groups".

How can I create a placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your placeholder option to the attr array like this:

```
$formBuilder
    ->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, array(
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'placeholder' => '...',
        ),
        'label' => 'Password',
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also place it directly in you twig file by using something like that 
**{{form.widget("password", {'attr':{'placeholder':"password placeholder here"}})}}**. This can be useful when you want local placeholder.